# Android avoiding observable being called while using ViewPager and LiveData

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

I've been struggling using ViewPager with LiveData. This is due to observables being called when a page isn't in view which results in null pointer exceptions. Since ViewPager manages fragments ex. creating fragments 1-2 swipes before or after you arrive on the page. getViewLifeCycleOwner doesn't seem to be useful since the view isn't destroyed when leaving the page. Is there a way to only have observables be called while the view is visible rather than following the view lifecycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the observables in `onResume` and cleaned up in `onPause`.